# How to send a JSON object to a servlet

Tags: java, javascript, json, spring, servlets

I want to send some data from my computer to a tomcat server which runs some servlets. And I also want to recieve the JSON from server. Can someone tell me is there a good framework or library to make things easy. I cannot send the data as URL parameters. I could find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099403/creating-json-object-in-javascript-and-sending-it-to-servlet). (I use spring MVC).

Comment: Use Apache HttpClient.

Comment: what is the issue with the question/answer you found?

Comment: it only tells how to send the JSON object only. I don't know where I receive the object and I don't know hot to send from a servlet.

Comment: You're already using Spring? Why are you looking for an additional framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome); [here](http://norrisshelton.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/spring-3-mvc-with-json-via-jackson-2-0/) a start tutorial to use with Spring MVC

Answer (score 1):

you can use Gson library. http://code.google.com/p/google-gson  , its simple and easy to convert JAVA object to Json and visa versa.